# java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null at com.bumptech.glide.util

Tags: android

I'm using a simplecursortreeadapter to adapt retrieving data from an external sqlite database to an expendablelistview. and I'm using a viewbinder to adapt views. the app before adding the third bloc(in which glide is) was working fine..but after adding the bloc ..the apps stops.

```
public class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder {

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    int viewID = view.getId();
    switch(viewID){
        case R.id.group1 :
            TextView groupName = (TextView) view;
            String groupname;
            groupname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1));
            groupName.setText(groupname);
            break;

        case R.id.child1 :
            TextView friendName = (TextView) view;
            String friend_name;
            friend_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1));
            friendName.setText(friend_name);
            break;


        case R.id.child2 :
            ImageView contactProfile = (ImageView) view;
            byte[] imageBytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2));
            if(imageBytes != null ){
                // Pic image from database
                contactProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length));
            }else {
                // If image not found in database , assign a default image
                contactProfile.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.child3 :
            String urls;
            urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
            ImageView url=findViewById(R.id.child3);
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

the build is successful and the apps opens but when i click on something the apps stops ..this is my error msg:

```
08-01 18:40:20.512 4772-4772/ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-01 18:40:20.585 4772-4772/ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava, PID: 4772
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:25)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:651)
        at ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava.MainActivity$MyViewBinder.setViewValue(MainActivity.java:99)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:220)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.bindChildView(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:254)
        at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getChildView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:251)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1494)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2171)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

this is version i'm using:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: with all respect..it's not duplicate ..i'm having a specific question and the problem is related to glide library ..i found this problem in other forums with no valid answers ..some suggested to use another type of library ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your query `urls` is `null`.

This line:

```
urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
```

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new to android ..do you mean in sqlite database if the cases are null? ..no they have all same url for testing: https://imgur.com/lxs1Yjg

Comment: Which is your line 99..??

Comment: before the Fatal EXCEPTION, there is an error: 08-01 19:06:19.193 5516-5516/ma.ac.iav.databasewithjava W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

Comment: this is my line 99:                     Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);

Comment: Then your urls or url is null. Debug for NPE.

Comment: if i use GlideApp as recommended in github it get highlighted red with no possible import class

Comment: is this line syntax correct   ImageView url=findViewById(R.id.child3);?

Comment: Try casting to (ImageView) view, similar to other cases.

Comment: 2/ i'm new to android ..so sorry for this question, how to do  Debug for NPE? and what possible action i'll have to do

Comment: i did cast imageview(view) and the apps stoped crushing ..but it didn't show any picture ..why?

Comment: NPE fixed - That’s for you to find out and learn. Image not loading, check the URL.

Comment: yeah the problem was with URL ..you can close the query now! i find my solutions ..thanks a lot

Comment: I have resolved my issue by using @GlideModule annotation

Answer (score 2):

the crash from:

```
ImageView url=findViewById(R.id.child3);
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urls).into(url);
```

Because url is null;
check your "R.id.child3"

Answer (score 2):

Check if the imageView is null

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to setup @GlideModule in the project

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.InputStream;

@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class, new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Now, use `GlideApp` instead of `Glide` in the entire project.